# How to convert nested dic of python coming in response using pandas.dataframe() function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

i am not able to convert the output as i desire:

```
x = {
     "urlCrawlErrorSample": [ 
         {
           "urlDetails": {
                           "containingSitemaps": ['asff','123'],
                           "linkedFromUrls": ['xcvxcvad','89767']
                          },
           "first_detected": "A String", 
           "pageUrl": "A String", 
           "responseCode": 42, 
           "last_crawled": "A String"
         }  
      ]
     }
```

what I applied :

```
df = 
pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(x['urlCrawlErrorSample']), orient='columns')
```

what i got,output:

```
df
  first_detected last_crawled   pageUrl  responseCode urlDetails.containingSitemaps urlDetails.linkedFromUrls
0       A String     A String  A String            42                   [asff, 123]         [xcvxcvad, 89767]
```

desired out put:

```
 df
  first_detected last_crawled   pageUrl  responseCode urlDetails.containingSitemaps urlDetails.linkedFromUrls
0       A String     A String  A String            42                          asff                  xcvxcvad
1       A String     A String  A String            42                          123                      89767
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this

```
x = {
 "urlCrawlErrorSample": [ 
     {
       "urlDetails": {
                       "containingSitemaps": ['asff','123'],
                       "linkedFromUrls": ['xcvxcvad','89767']
                      },
       "first_detected": "A String", 
       "pageUrl": "A String", 
       "responseCode": 42,       
 "last_crawled": "A String"
     }  
  ]
 }

a = pd.DataFrame(x['urlCrawlErrorSample']*2)
b = pd.DataFrame(x['urlCrawlErrorSample'][0]['urlDetails'])
print( pd.concat([a,b], axis=1).drop('urlDetails', axis=1) )
```

Output

```
  first_detected last_crawled   pageUrl  responseCode containingSitemaps  \
0       A String     A String  A String            42               asff   
1       A String     A String  A String            42                123   

  linkedFromUrls  
0       xcvxcvad  
1          89767
```